# How to force rendering if the global variable value changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
#File 1:
let ticketEnable = false;

export default class SupportTicketMain extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  render () {
    let expandIcon = <DownIcon/>;
    if (this.state.ticketDetailExpanded) {
      expandIcon = <UpIcon/>;
    }
    return (
      <Section className="ticketMain" primary={true}>
        <TicketHeader expanded={ticketEnable}/>
      </Section>
    );
  }
};

export function setTicketEnablement (value) {
    ticketEnable = value;
}


#file 2:

import { setTicketEnablement } from file1;

export default class SupportTicketTabs extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ticketDetailExpanded: false
    };

    this._expandClick = this._expandClick.bind(this);
  }

  _expandClick() {
    this.setState({ticketDetailExpanded: !this.state.ticketDetailExpanded});
    setTicketEnablement(this.state.ticketDetailExpanded);
  }

  render () {
    let expandIcon = <DownIcon/>;
    if (this.state.ticketDetailExpanded) {
        expandIcon = <UpIcon/>;
    }

    return (
          <Button className="expander" type="icon" onClick={this._expandClick}>
             {expandIcon}
          </Button>
    );
  }
};
```

Here a button click in supportTicketTabs class of #file2 will update global variable in #File1 , but SupportTicketMain render doesn't update if the global variable value changes! please guide me on this.

Comment: where do you call `SupportTicketTabs` component?

Comment: In the file #3 as                                                                                    class Main extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <App centered={false}>
        <SupportTicketMain />
        <SupportTicketTabs />
      </App>
    );
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ticketEnable` should be a prop passed into `SupportTicketMain`. The component that wraps both `SupportTicketTabs` and `SupportTicketMain` should be handing down a callback as a prop that modifies the value of `ticketEnable` (`toggleTicketEnable`) and the value of `ticketEnable`

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onToggleTicketEnable = this.onToggleTicketEnable.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      ticketEnabled: false;
    };
  }
  onToggleTicketEnable() {
    this.setState({ ticketEnabled: !this.state.ticketEnabled });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <App centered={false}>
        <SupportTicketMain ticketEnable={this.ticketEnabled} />
        <SupportTicketTabs onToggleTicketEnable={this.onToggleTicketEnable}/>
      </App>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Working!! Thanks a lot @Petersen... thanks for guiding me the correct approach.